# Accessing web site by HTTPS is breaking database connection

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a codeigniter site running on a Apache web server 
I installed an SSL from letsencrypt

My site works fine if I access it through http://example.com

but,

If I access it through https://example.com the site shows but the database is broken

This is my htaccess file

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.org
        ServerAlias www.example.org
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule   "^/resources/(.+)" "https://example.org/_resources/$1"$
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        ProxyPass /api https://localhost:8010/api
        ProxyPassReverse /api https://localhost:8010/api
</VirtualHost>
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.org
    ServerAlias www.example.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org-0001/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Could you more carefully describe: "the database is broken". What exactly happens?

Comment: So when I hit my site with "http" everything works,  all links, all dynamic content being pulled from the database everything is working like its supposed to. When I hit my site with "https" only the homepage works but no links work as well a the dynamic content on the homepage is blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this issue by adding inside of the `<VirtualHost *:443>` tag

```
  <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All 
  </Directory>
```